# Link to a section of a webpage

Tags: html, hyperlink

I want to make a link that when clicked, sends you to a certain line on the page (or another page). I know this is possible, but how do I do it?

Comment: use anchors.  Using an anchor tag with `#something` as the href will cause the page to go to whatever element has that id (in this case "something") in your document.

Comment: joseph - why did you type that as a comment? that's pretty much the answer and I will plus it if you convert it to one.

Comment: so... if I have a <div> tag with the id something and have a link that looks something like "<a href="#something">text</a>" it will take you there?

Comment: one more question on that. How do I do that when going from page1.html to a div tag on page2.html? (asked the same question below)

Comment: see bozdoz's answer. notice the #answers addition to the end of the url.

Comment: @KaiQing sorry :P I left that for someone else because I'm busy with other stuff *cough* finals *cough* and didn't want to build a full blown answer and demo.  It's sufficiently answered by others now, however.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

your jump link looks like this

```
<a href="#div_id">jump link</a>
```

Then make

```
<div id="div_id"></div>
```

the jump link will take you to that div

Comment: one more question on that. How do I do that when going from page1.html to a div tag on page2.html?

Comment: Your jump link would be `(URL or path)page.html#div_id`

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira can you please explain more in detail what you want.

Answer (score 32):

Hashtags at the end of the URL bring a visitor to the element with the ID: e.g.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424785/link-to-a-section-of-a-webpage#answers
```

Would bring you to where the DIV with the ID 'answers' begins.  Also, you can use the name attribute in anchor tags, to create the same effect.

[Resource](http://www.utoronto.ca/web/HTMLdocs/NewHTML/a_name.html)

Comment: What if the section where I want to go has no id, but only class?

Comment: There is no built-in way to scroll to a class via the URL address bar

Comment: A hashtag is a means of indicating that a term, in plain text, should be hyperlinked to a search engine on social media networks. It gets the name because it it uses a hash character to prefix it. Please don’t confuse other uses of the hash character with hashtags.

Comment: Sorry, should have called it "jump link" :P

Answer (score 13):

The fragment identifier (also known as: Fragment IDs, Anchor Identifiers, Named Anchors) introduced by a hash mark # is the optional last part of a URL for a document. It is typically used to identify a portion of that document.

```
<a href="http://www.someuri.com/page#fragment">Link to fragment identifier</a>
```

Syntax for URIs also allows an optional query part introduced by a question mark ?. In URIs with a query and a fragment the fragment follows the query.

```
<a href="http://www.someuri.com/page?query=1#fragment">Link to fragment with a query</a>
```

When a Web browser requests a resource from a Web server, the agent sends the URI to the server, but does not send the fragment. Instead, the agent waits for the server to send the resource, and then the agent (Web browser) processes the resource according to the document type and fragment value.

Named Anchors `<a name="fragment">` are deprecated in XHTML 1.0, the ID attribute is the suggested replacement. `<div id="fragment"></div>`

Answer (score 4):

If you are a user and not a site developer, you can do it as follows:

```
https://example.com/index.html#:~:text=foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

Use `<section>`.

and use `<a href="page.html#tips">Visit the Useful Tips Section</a>`

[w3school.com/html_links](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp)

Comment: It is not limited to sections, and the other answers (from 5 years ago) are already correct.

Comment: This example is incomplete. Please include how the "tips" name would be defined.