# Show/Hide elements on a single page using <a> or <span>

Tags: html, css, onclick, display

I am showing or hiding divs elements on a single page using jQuery depending on what is clicked:

HTML:

```
<div id='aboutPage' class='visible'>
//content
</div>

<div id='contactPage' class='invis'>
//content
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.visible { display: block; }
.invis { display: none; }
```

JS:

```
$('#element1').on('click', {clickedTab: 'aboutTab'}, changeTab);
$('#element2').on('click', {clickedTab: 'contactTab'}, changeTab);

var currentTab = 'about';

function changeTab(event)
{
//if-else ladder to make invis the prior current tab
if (currentTab == 'about')
    if (event.data.clickedTab != 'aboutTab')
        $('#aboutPage').removeClass('visible').addClass('invis');
    else return;
else if (currentTab == 'contact')
    if (event.data.clickedTab != 'contactTab')
        $('#contactPage').removeClass('visible').addClass('invis');
    else return;

//if-else ladder to change the current tab
if (event.data.clickedTab == 'aboutTab') {
    currentTab = 'about';
    $('#aboutPage').removeClass('invis').addClass('visible');
}
else if (event.data.clickedTab == 'contactTab') {
    currentTab = 'contact';
    $('#contactPage').removeClass('invis').addClass('visible');
}
```

My question is, is it appropriate for `element1` and `element2` to be `<a>` elements, even though they don't technically link to another page? I would like to do this so that stylistically the elements appear to be links to the user. Or, should I make them `<span>` elements and then just style them to look like links using CSS? Is there any difference? Would the `<a>` option be considered bad coding style?

Comment: Not at all.....

Comment: It may have some effect on your seo, but I'm not much familier in that field so can't be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, is it appropriate for `element1` and `element2` to be `<a>` elements, even though they don't technically link to another page?

There is no requirement that an anchor element link to another page. An anchor element, when used with the `href` attribute, creates a link. That link can go anywhere: within the same page, an e-mail address, another page, etc.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element

Comment: I know it's not a requirement; my question was more one of style, as in, would an experienced developer tend to use `<a>` or `<span>` for this purpose? Still, your answer indicates that using `<a>` is perfectly acceptable in this context, so I've marked it as solved. I ended up using `<a>` in conjunction with [jump links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424785/link-to-a-section-of-a-webpage).

Comment: If it's a hyperlink you're after, `<a>` is the right way to go. Jump links are a perfect example. In fact, the link in my answer is the target of a jump link from the table of contents in the [**specification**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html).

Answer (score 1):

Screen Readers will parse pages and provide content audibly for the visually impaired. One of the ways the visually impaired scan a page is to get a "list of links" on the page. If you are navigating between experiences (showing and hiding content), it makes sense to use a `BUTTON` or an `A` element. Using a `SPAN` is ambiguous, and does not make for an accessible web.

If another user has a disability which prohibits the usage of a mouse (or equivalent), and is limited to keyboard navigation of a page, a `SPAN` will never achieve focus when tabbing through a page, whereas an `A` element or a `BUTTON` will.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">your link</a>
```

Specifying the aforementioned HREF attribute will prevent your page from jumping around, and allow your javascript to handle the transitions as you intend.