# How do I link headings with it's paragraph on the same page

Tags: html

I am confused, how to link my webpage heading to its paragraph?

My heading is in HTML:

```
<h6><span style="color: #ff00ff;"><strong>Advanced Filter vs. AutoFilter
```

and paragraph is

```
<h2><strong>Advanced Filter vs. AutoFilter</strong></h2>
<p style="text-align: justify;">Auto Filter works within a fixed data-set and can 
filter by cell color, by font color, by cell value and so on.
“Advanced Filter” works with data only, not like cell color or font color etc.</p>
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Link to a section of a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424785/link-to-a-section-of-a-webpage)

Answer (score 0):

change like this...

```
<h6><a href="#top"><span style="color: #ff00ff;"><strong>Advanced Filter vs. AutoFilter</strong></span></a></h6>
```

and in paragraph...

```
<p  id="top" style="text-align: justify;">Auto Filter works within a fixed data-set 
and can 
filter by cell color, by font color, by cell value and so on.
“Advanced Filter” works with data only, not like cell color or font color 
etc.</p>
```