# Navigating within the page using hyperlinks in velocity Template

Tags: widget, velocity

I am trying to build a summary section for a velocity template.How can we navigate to different sections of the page using velocity scripting.

I am new to velocity. Please help me out in this.

Thanks!

Comment: where is your code? share it

Answer (score 0):

Navigate within page is an HTML [feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424785/link-to-a-section-of-a-webpage) using link to specific id.

You can use velocity to hold and use same [variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424785/link-to-a-section-of-a-webpage) for each section:

```
 #set( $section_one = "nav1" )
 <a href="#$section_one">first </a>
 .....

 <div id="$section_one"></div>
```