# Using HREF to scroll above an element

Tags: html, css

is there any way to scroll above an element?
I mean, the following "H3" tag for example:

```
<h3 class="TEST" id="TEST">TEST</h3>
<p>TEXT</p>
```

I would like to jump **a little above** this "TEST" element using HREF:

```
<a href="#TEST">
```

like 5px above. is there any way to do it?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Link to a section of a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424785/link-to-a-section-of-a-webpage)

Comment: @Abhishek Thanks, but I have already done an HREF and it works fine, I need to jump a little bit above this element.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534661/make-anchor-link-go-some-pixels-above-where-its-linked-to This post helped me.
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 4):

### I think solution you are looking for is this

let's say you have this

```
<h3 class="TEST jump" id="TEST">TEST</h3>
```

so what you need to do is

```
.TEST {
scroll-margin-top: 5px;
}
```

This way after clicking

```
<a href="#TEST">
```

you will jump a 5px above h3

about accesibility: [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=scroll-margin-top)

Answer (score 1):

If you set a custom class for this `h3`

```
<h3 class="TEST jump" id="TEST">TEST</h3>
```

then you could add CSS like so:

```
.jump {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -250px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```