# Hyperlink to ID is non responsive

Tags: html, web, hyperlink

I've created a hyper link to a section in my website, however when I click on the link it does not take me to the section of the website. I have used an anchor tag and everything appears to be okay with the code. I have no idea what to do.

HTML CODE:

```
<p>
You can view them <a href="#portfolio"><strong>here</strong></a>.
</p>
```

Comment: please post your complete code snippet here.answer of yor question here you can see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424785/link-to-a-section-of-a-webpage/8424807

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p><a href="#C4">You can view them</a></p>

<h2>Chapter 1</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2>Chapter 2</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2>Chapter 3</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>


<h2 id="C4">Chapter 4</h2>
<p>Here view</p>

<h2>Chapter 5</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>



</body>
</html>
```

**Verify my answer if it work for you.**

Comment: that is basically what my code writes but still doesn't work at all.

Comment: Copy my code and try because in your code you forgot to give id to ```<p>...</p>```.