# How to make header clickable?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanna have the feature on my website that if I click one of the topbar navigation elements in the header I wanna be in this section on the website. For example if I click here "How":[image]

I wanna land here:[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: I pretty sure this is a duplicate to [Link to a section of a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424785/link-to-a-section-of-a-webpage/8424807) or [Linking to a specific part of a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481911/linking-to-a-specific-part-of-a-web-page) (and likely many more), if not then please explain why.

Answer (score 0):

If it's on the same page, look into [making headings link targets](https://developers.google.com/style/headings-targets). The premise being the `a` tags in your nav point to an `id` on a heading tag e.g.

```html
<a href="#about-us">...</a>

<!-- will take you to: -->

<h2 id="about-us">About us</h2>
```

Comment: Before answering a question you should check if it has already been answered here on SO. And if your answer does not include any new information compared to those you should leave a comment pointing to that answer(s)  instead of writing a new one with basically the same content. (or vote to close it as soon as you have enough reputation)

Answer (score 0):

To get a smooth scrolling experience instead of jumping to an anchor, you can achieve this by by using an [eventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) on the header. Then using the [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) of the how element to get its position on the page.
You can then scroll the window object to the position of the how Element.

```js
let header = document.getElementById('hacker-header');
let how = document.getElementById('how');
header.addEventListener('click', () => {
  window.scrollTo({
    top: how.getBoundingClientRect().y,
    left: how.getBoundingClientRect().x,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
});
```

```css
body {
background: black;
}
h1 {
 color:lime;
}
#high {
   height: 5000px;
   width:200px;
   background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(112,135,95,1) 0%, rgba(21,55,31,1) 35%, rgba(7,121,5,1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<header id="hacker-header">
<h1>Hacker</h1>
</header>
<div id="high">
</div>
<footer id="how">
<h1>How</h1>
</footer>
```

Comment: Why JavaScript if one could just use `scroll-behavior: smooth;` for a smooth scrolling experience?